# addClass not applying

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, addclass

```
message = "<span>prefix text</span> some more text"; // comes down like this
message = $("<div></div>").append(message);
message.filter("span:first").addClass("prefix");
$("#messages").append(message);
```

message.html() shows the span has no class after this operation, as well as developer mode in IE when looking at the dom source.

```
$(message).addClass("test"); //does not work either
```

What am I not understanding about this? ty.

Comment: I don't know if you notice that append message, to element #message it's missing the the quotes `"`

Comment: In your actual script is `message` already a jQuery object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.find` method instead of `.filter`:

```
message.find("span:first").addClass("prefix");
```

Comment: ...and for what it's worth, I'm always mixing `find()` and `filter()` up too.

Answer (score 0):

Tidy up a bit and try again:

```
var addon = "<span>prefix text</span> some more text"; 
var message = $("<div></div>").append(addon); 

message.find("span:first").addClass("prefix"); 
$("#messages").append(message);

$(message).addClass("test"); // < What is the purpose of this?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var msgtext = "<span>prefix text</span> some more text", 
    message = $("<div></div>").append(msgtext);

message.find("span:first-child").addClass("prefix");

$("#messages").append(message);
```